# what is the optimize code for this

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `string1, string2,...,stringn`
and values of each strings are

`string1 = "s1k1-s1k2-s1k3-....-s1kn | s1v1-s1v2-s1v3-....-s1vn";`

`string2 = "s2k1-s2k2-s2k3-....-s2kn | s2v1-s2v2-s2v3-....-s2vn";`

```
                .............
```

`stringn = "snk1-snk2-snk3-....-snkn | snv1-snv2-snv3-....-snvn";`

Now, I want to populate the `Dictionary<string, string>()` with the key and values as follows.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add(s1k1, s1v1);
dict.Add(s1k2, s1v2);
         :
         :
dict.Add(snkn, snvn);
```

**Below is my sample code:**

```
        string string1 = "s1k1-s1k2-s1k3-s1kn|s1v1-s1v2-s1v3-s1vn";
        string string2 = "s2k1-s2k2-s2k3-s2kn|s2v1-s2v2-s2v3-s2vn";
        string stringn = "snk1-snk2-snk3-snkn|snv1-snv2-snv3-snvn";

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        new List<string> { string1, string2, stringn }.ForEach(str =>
        {
            var strSplit = str.Split('|');
            var strKeys = strSplit[0].Split('-');
            var strValues = strSplit[1].Split('-');
            strKeys.Zip(strValues, (key, value) => new { key, value }).ToList().ForEach(filed => dict.Add(filed.key, filed.value));
        });
```

Is it possible to optimize this code ?

Comment: This might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is [asked on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17697/how-to-optimize-this-c-code).

Comment: Yes, After KeyboardP suggested i posted the same question on CodeReview also. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind the most costly operation here in terms of memory usage is `strSplit = str.Split('|')`. It creates two large strings that go directly to a garbage after `strKeys` and `strValues` are obtained. Later all these garbage strings will be collected by garbage collector which will negatively affect the performance.

The `strKeys` and `strValues` string arrays contain strings that will be used in `dict`, so the memory loss here is minimal.

To optimize memory usage you'll have to traverse `str` char-by-char and create keys and values using `StringBuilder` class. In this case memory loss will be minimal, however your code won't be as clean as it is now. So I would recommend such solution only if this part of the code is the real performance bottleneck in your application.